# Import files in python with a for loop and a list of names

Tags: python, string, python-import

I am trying to import many files. I have a list (myList) of strings that are the names of the files of the modules that I want to import. All of the files which I want to import are in a directory called parentDirectory. This directory is in the folder that this code is in.

What I have so far is:

```
myList = {'fileOne', 'fileTwo', 'fileThree'}
for toImport in myList:
    moduleToImport = 'parentDirectory.'+toImport
    import moduleToImport
```

This code just treats moduleToImport as a module's name, but I want the code to understand that it is a variable for a string.

```
This is the Error Code:
dule>
    import moduleToImport
ImportError: No module named moduleToImport
```

Comment: Try - `import importlib; importedModule = importlib.import_module(moduleToImport)` Then you can use the imported module using `importedModule` .

Comment: You actually have a set not a list

Comment: you could move these files to a module and just import the module

Comment: Thank you Anand, that works for me. Also, thanks for letting me know Padraic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the same effect as `import <modulename>` , then one way to do it would be to import the module using [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) , and then use `globals()` function to get the global namespace and add the imported module using the same name there.

Code -

```
myList = {'fileOne', 'fileTwo', 'fileThree'}
import importLib
gbl = globals()
for toImport in myList:
    moduleToImport = 'parentDirectory.'+toImport
    gbl[moduleToImport] = importlib.import_module(moduleToImport)
```

Then later on you can use -

```
parentDirectory.fileOne.<something>
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import importlib
>>> globals()['b'] = importlib.import_module('b')
>>> b.myfun()
Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myList = ['fileOne', 'fileTwo', 'fileThree']
modules = map(__import__, myList)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the file path in the answer? So that I can refer to files in a different directory?

Comment: imp.load_source(module_name, file_path)